# Modeling an infinite delay system

Tags: linear-systems, delay

If black holes swallow everything and assumes that the black holes do not get out the things from them, then can we consider a black hole as an infinite delay system? It takes the input and it is a super slow system that has an infinite delay so they do not give an output?

If yes, How can model such a system? I thought about modeling the system like this:

y(x) = x + jz.

where x is the input and j is the imaginary part. z is a parameter within the system(black hole) itself.

the phase shift for such a system can be given by:

tan-1(z/x) and this quantity must approaches to infinity which is impossible since the maximum value for the function is pi/2. So how can we adjust the parameter z to give the infinite delay?

A side note: I gave the black hole as an example, so the question is mainly about how to model the infinite delay system.

Comment: Maybe as $y(t)=0$ ?

Comment: @MBaz sorry the parameter is z not y. So, the parameter z  has nothing to do with output. Yes, y(t) = 0. However, I want the system to have an infinite delay, but not zero output  (I don't know if this a valid argument)

Comment: So what is the output for $t<\infty$?

Comment: @MBaz based on my question it's zero.

Comment: @MBaz I see your point here, it's meaningless to talk about phase shift and the output is zero. Based on my understanding the maximum phase shift is pi/2 (based on tan-1) So if I want to shift the signal by 5000 years, how can I do this?

Comment: $y(t)=x(t-5000)$ (where time is measured in years). Note that a factor $\text{exp}(j\phi)$ is equivalent to a time delay only for sine and cosine signals.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite delay means  nothing happen. You can assume uncontrollability or you can assume a system with zero dynamics and zero gain and some arbitrary initial condition.